# iPhone compile dependent on target

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, target

I have project with multiple targets for multiple clients however the most of the application is very much the same and so far I was able to control the different program flow with property lists read at run-time.

One client has a specific view that I need to show before all others.

My problem is that I am getting a build error (actually a link error) because because the controller class is not in the other clients target and I also do not want to include it. So I was looking for some compile time control.

I am looking for something like

```
#ifdef client1target
     ... do something
#else
     ... do something else
#endif
```

The part of the program I have trouble with looks at the moment like this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    NSString *client = [myEnvVariables getShortName]; // In this class method I read the plist

    if ([client isEqualToString:@"CLIENT1"]) {

        Client1SpecificController *mm = [[Client1SpecificController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Client1SpecificView" bundle:nil];
// here happens the compile error because Client1SpecificController is not known at other targets

        mm.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,20,320,460);

        [window addSubview:mm.view];
        [window makeKeyAndVisible]; 

    } else {

        [window addSubview:navigationController.view];
        [window makeKeyAndVisible]; 
    }

    return YES;
}
```

The error looks like this

```
undefined symbols:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Client1SpecificController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-Client1SpecificController in myAppDelegate.o
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

open the settings of one target and go to "Preprocessor Macros" set there anything you like for example `CLIENT_ONE`

then you can use this in your code as described

```
#ifdef CLIENT_ONE
    #import "ClassOneController.h"
#else
    #import "OtherController.h"
#endif
```

Here is a screenshot of the build setting for the target:
[image: For This Example add CLIENT_ONE = 1]